# "soft demands" in Azure DevOps pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, agent

I am currently writing pipelines for Azure DevOps Service 2022 where I do Matrix builds for different architectures and either use native Agent or emulated.
(E.g. ARM runs emulated, ARM64 on a ARM64 server)
Currently I set a demand to the agents with the correct architecture
But what I would like to have is a fallback Like: use the ARM64 server if there are available agent, but if not use any server (and Fallback to Emulation)
Is this possible somehow?

Setting demands fails if no such agent is available